# meaning of an integral in the continuity equation

Tags: electromagnetism

This is about continuity equation. What does the last integral mean? 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Q_V}{\mathrm{d}t}=\iiint_V \mathrm{d}^3x \,\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=-\iiint_V\! \mathrm{d}^3x\,\operatorname{div}\,\mathbf{j}=-\iint\limits_{\partial V}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\;\;\;\subset\!\supset \mathbf j\;\cdot\mathbf n\,{d}S\,,$$

EDIT:
And what does $\partial V$ mean? Why not S like surface?

Comment: $\partial V$ is just the standard notation for boundary of the region $V$.

Comment: BTW it is a very sensible definition: the boundary *is* a derivative of the volume, in some proper sense. Note that even dimensionally, the surface has the same dimension as the volume divided by $x$, just like the derivative. In homology theory, $\partial$ is the boundary operator. It squares to zero: $\partial^2=0$. It means the fact that the boundary is a closed manifold - the boundary of a boundary is nothing.

Comment: Related [meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6779/oiint-doesnt-seem-to-work) and +1 for the effort in implementing $\oiint$!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last integral is a surface integral. It is the fluid (current) flux crossing the volume surface integrated over the whole surface. It is how much charge is leaving the volume per second. ($\partial V$ means boundary of V and you sum all local $j_\bot dS$.)

Comment: dV is a slice of a volume right? But why is partial V the boundary?

Comment: It is not a partial derivative; it is a mathematical notation that reads "boundary of V". In other words, it is $S$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the range of integration has changed from $V$ meaning over the volume to $\partial{V}$ and that the variable of integration has changed from $\text{d}^3x$ to $\text{d}S$.

It means an integral over the surface that bounds the volume.

The closed curve over the integration signs implies that the surface must be closed.

---

This expression is an application of what physicist tend to call [Gauss's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law), and mathematicians tend to know as the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).